# Insert Into Statement causes ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: c#, oracle, devart, ora-01756

Environment: 
DevArt Drivers for Oracle
.NET 4.5

I'm trying to execute the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO T_CUSTOMERS_T
  ("ID",        "NAME1",            "NAME2",   "NAME",          "STREET",
   "POSTAL",    "CITY",             "COUNTRY", "TEL",           "MAIL",
   "STATE",     "STATE_EX",         "REF") 
VALUES
  (N'23frRRrg', N'Peter',           N'Hansel',  N'Peter Hansel', N'Flowerpowerstreet 5',
   N'88558',    N'New York',        N'US',      N'1801810',      N'info@fixmeplease.com',
   N'VALID',    N'Record is valid', NULL);
```

I got the following exception from the devart driver:

```
Type: OracleException
Message: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Call Stack:    at Devart.Data.Oracle.ax.c(Int32 A_0)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.b9.a(String A_0)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.InternalPrepare(Boolean implicitPrepare, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at DataConnection.AddRecords(TableMetadata TableStructure, Dictionary`2[] Records)
```

**EDIT:**

I executed the statement with the odbc oracle driver and it works fine. I'll update the devart driver tomorrow and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Hello from [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: is there reason to use UTF-16 literals? does it work without 'N'? Also there is not reason to put column names into quotes.

Comment: I need to support unicode characters. I will post the C# code for you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Based on the DevArt documentation [OracleDataAdapter](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataAdapter.html)

```
INSERT INTO myTable(col1,col2col5,col7) VALUES ('data1','data2','data3',NULL)
```

Comment: While I'll agree that there's no real reason to double-quote the column names, nor (as far as I can see) to use Unicode literals, I do not believe these things would cause the errors that OP is experiencing. Would you care to edit your answer and explain what you believe is incorrect in OP's query? Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis it is questionable how this SQL string is wrapped into source code, and what exactly is passed to the database. Also DevArt drivers are not official Oracle ones, but something based on reverse-engenering. So it is questionable whether these drivers even support Unicode literals.

Comment: @LeBaptiste The names of the columns are specified by the user. I need to quote them :)

Comment: If you need to specify the columns, after concatenation/formatting you should not have any double quote left.

String.Format("INSERT INTO myTable({0},{1}.{2})",col1,col2,col3);  etc...